# Map is not a function in React Hooks

Tags: reactjs

I was surfing by the internet and found a lot of same problems. And this is not the first time when i bumbped in exactly same issue. However, i still cant figure out the cause  of it.

I have to display data from api /users. Each of user has to be filled in html-block. I've written in separate file get and post queries.

For instance "/users" shows me:

```
{"success":true,"total_pages":10,"total_users":46,"count":5,"page":1,"links":{"next_url":"https:xxx\/api\/v1\/users?page=2&count=5","prev_url":null},"users":[{"id":1682 ....
```

So, now i want it to display data in react. However, i have issue with following text: "users.map is not a function".

```
export default function ListItems() {
  const defaultUser = {
    id: null,
    photo: '',
    position: 0,
    name: '',
    email: '',
    phone: '',
  }

  const [users, setUsers] = useState(defaultUser)

  useEffect(() => {
    displayUsers()
  }, [])

  const displayUsers = () => {
    API
      .getUsers()
      .then(response => {
        setUsers(response.data)
        console.log(response.data)
      })
      .catch(event => console.log(event))
  }

  return (
    <ul className="list">
      {
        users && users.map(user => {
          return (
            <li className="item" key={ user.id }>
              <img className="item__photo" src={ user.photo } alt="user-1"/>

              <div className="item__name">
                <h3 className="subtitle">{user.name}</h3>
              </div>

              <div className="item__description">
                <h3 className="description">{user.position}</h3>
                <h3 className="description">{user.email}</h3>
                <h3 className="description">{user.phone}</h3>
              </div>
            </li>
          )
        })
      }
    </ul>
  )
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code? Is there an error? [Edit] to explain the problem and quote any errors or warnings in full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the answer before, this happens because `users` is not an array.

This happens because you set the state to default `user` to a `map` (see below)

Change

```
  const defaultUser = { // < -- THIS IS A MAP
    id: null,
    photo: '',
    position: 0,
    name: '',
    email: '',
    phone: '',
  }

  const [users, setUsers] = useState(defaultUser)
```

To

```
  const defaultUsers = [{
    id: null,
    photo: '',
    position: 0,
    name: '',
    email: '',
    phone: '',
  }]

  const [users, setUsers] = useState(defaultUsers)
```

EDIT:
As per the author findings, this part should be fixed too:
`setUsers(response.data))` -> `setUsers(response.data.users))`

Comment: god.... i realised what i've done wrong....didn't get to the data properly (just needed to setUsers(response.data.users))
sorry for wasting your time....

Comment: happy to help. what i wrote is also valid, this will fix your initial render too

Answer (score -1):

Simply: if `user` variable is null/undefined or not an array `users.map(` throws **Map is not a function** error.